# R officer plots associated to excel sheet

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I have recently started learning about `officer` to try to automatize ppt creation. When I manually construct PPTs, I can easily change an incorrect number which automatically updates the chart.
[image: Changing data of plot]
Is there any way to achieve this functionality with `officer`? Are there any other alternatives in case this is not possible?

Comment: no, it's not possible with officer. I am not aware of alternatives.

Comment: If we were talking about excel instead of powerpoint, then [BERT](http://bert-toolkit.com/)  would be worth exploring in my opinion.